# How to tell ASP.NET MVC to look for controllers in a library?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly

This must be a trivial question to some, but I haven't found any actual information about this.

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application. As I like to write reusable code, I'd like to put my Controllers into a separate library assembly and reuse them across multiple web applications.

The question is, how can I tell ASP.NET MVC that it should look for controllers in the other assembly instead of the web application itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your own ControllerFactory.

Check out [this](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/11/14/how-to-call-controllers-in-external-assemblies-in-an-asp.net.aspx) link

Basically, create the ControllerFactory as described above, then in your Global.asax, add this line:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new YourFactory());
```

Which tells ASP.NET MVC to use your ControllerFactory.

The kicker is when you define your routes, you need to give ASP.NET MVC a "hint" as to where this assembly is located:

```
yourRoute.DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary(
    new
    {
         namespaces = new[] { "SomeAssembly.Controllers" }
    });
```

If it doesnt find it, then it looks in the regular namespace (Web Application).

[Here](http://nayyeri.net/custom-controller-factory-in-asp-net-mvc) is another link showing how to create a Custom Controller Factory.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Actually, simply specifying the namespace in which my controllers reside was enough to do the trick!

Comment: Cool. I've never tried the whole namespace thing, but i currently use Controller factories for dependency injection. Glad it worked.